# Get only checked in files from TFS as part of TFS build

Tags: powershell, tfs, msbuild, tfs-2015, tfvc

I have Continuous integration checked for my folder in TFS which triggers a build in TFS2015 . Now as part of by Build Definition, I want to add a step which would identify and pull only those files which were checked in as part of the changeset which triggered the current build and copy them to a target location.

A powershell script may be? Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a Powershell script task in your build definition to do this. A simple script for your reference:

```
$changesetid = $Env:Build_SourceVersion
$TFSURI = $Env:System_TeamFoundationCollectionUri
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($TFSURI)
$vcs = $tfs.GetService("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer")
$cs = $vcs.GetChangeset($changesetid)
foreach ($change in $cs.Changes)
{
    $change.Item.DownloadFile('D:\a\test\' + $change.Item.ServerItem.Substring(1))
}
```

This code just get the changed items, if the changeset includes other changes like deletion, you may need to add code to check this.

And you also need to import the TFS Client Library to use this script, refer to this link for details: [PowerShell and TFS: The Basics and Beyond](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/04/21/powershell-and-tfs-the-basics-and-beyond/).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible in TFS 2015. TFS 2017 has introduced the ability to "don't sync sources", after which you can perform your own get operation. You could try cloaking the whole repository on the repository tab and then creating a CI TFVC Include trigger definition on the trigger tab to recreate this behavior.

Then you can use the `tfpt getcs` option to get the changes of the changeset. You should be able to get the version from the builds `Build.SourceVersion` variable. You can get `tfpt` by installing the Team Foundation Server Power Tools 2015 and Team Explorer 2015 on the build server.

Comment: Thanks. You said its not possible in TFS2015, and yet asking to install TFS power tools 2015 and team explorer 2015? Also when you said perform own get operation, are you suggesting a powershell task?

Comment: To perform your own get operation you must be able to disable the fetching of sources. That is a TFS 2017+ feature.

Comment: To use the Team Foundation Power Tools you need their latest version, which is 2015 unfortunately. To use the 2015 power tools you'll need team explorer 2015.

Comment: To run tfpt you can use a batch script, powershell script, bash script or anything else that can execute executables.

Comment: PS just getting changed files can be a dangerous business. What about deletions? Renames? Restored files? Moved files? Empty directories?

Comment: do u have a sample PS script which shows how to get the files of changeset using tfpt...sorry...running into time crunch :(